# unable to start many Python programs in Ubuntu 11.4

Tags: python, ipython

I have recently begun using Ubuntu.  I am a reasonably experienced programmer, and have been using the "old" Python for years.  But, in Python 3.2, when I try to run one of several different programs which I installed from .eg, I get an error message similar to the one pasted below.

Here, I am trying to start IPython.  But the error is happening for others as well.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./ipython3", line 9, in <module>

load_entry_point('ipython==0.12', 'console_scripts', 'ipython3')()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py3.2.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.24-y3.2.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2279, in load_entry_point
raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))

ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'ipython3') not found
```

I have googled this error, and found that other users have been having similar problems, but as far as I can see, nobody has reported a real solution.

Comment: I might be very wrong here, but from what I understand, ipython is more for python use with the .NET platform. As such, I don't know if this usable on Linux. See if you can use just python

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, are you thinking of [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) instead?

Comment: @Makato: yes. I saw ipython and thought of IronPython.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget ipython is probably "Interactive Python", an alternative python interpreter.

Comment: @mlefavor: It's not strictly an interpreter; IPython is an interactive shell for a Python interpreter. But you're right, "Interactive" is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have mixed distro installs with easy_installs.

Probably the best way to experiment and work with Python is to use a separated "sandbox". With virtualenv (it is one of the several ways) it can be done as follows:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.2 --distribute MYPYTHON32
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.2
New python executable in MYPYTHON32/bin/python3.2
Also creating executable in MYPYTHON32/bin/python
Installing distribute...
```

Then you can install whatever you want to play with:

```
$ cd MYPYTHON32
$ bin/easy_install ipython
```

I have no problem:

```
$ bin/ipython3
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Dec  8 2011, 15:26:58) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

[Documentation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) on virtualenv will give you more hints. This way possible install will not interfere with system pythons and you always has control on what you install in the sandbox.